# Custom Add New Item Form Not Loading After Solution Upgrade

Tags: 2010, solution-package, custom-form, feature-upgrade

On my farm solution, I am creating custom Site Collection Definition, Content Type and new List based on that Content Type.

For the List, I created custom form and added it to the list Schema.xml as follows

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" 
            SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\PostList\NewPost.aspx" 
            WebPartZoneID="Main" UseLegacyForm="TRUE"  />
```

Where "PostList" is my custom list, and "NewPost.aspx" is my custom add new item form.

Now this custom form is new thing I added, the previous version of my WSP is already deployed and it created the Site Definition, Content Type, List Instance. When I do upgrade using (stsadm -o upgreadesolution...), the form get deployed in the 14 hive but when I click add new item, the popup opens with disabled ribbon and nothing in its content.

I tried deleting the Site Collection and creating it again using my custom Site Definition, it works fine and clicking add new item gives me my custom form. However, I can not delete the site collection and recreate it in the production, can anyone let me know what is my problem with this custom form and upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the old form was associated on list creation. In this case you should updete list instance. You can look at [this post](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2011/12/23/sharepoint-2010-create-and-update-list-forms-programmatically/), there is an example how to change a form. I think you can do these steps to solve your issue.